# How can I fix the 'invalid command name' error when using the 'dict' command in TCL version 8.6 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dictionary, ubuntu, command, tcl

when i execute a tcl file by using dctionnary command **dict**, i obtain error's message , as follow:

**invalid command name "dict"**.

for information i use  TCL version  8.6 on ubuntu 20.04.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sure you're not using 8.5? -- include a [mcve] that raises the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` command is built directly into Tcl from version 8.5 onwards. Here is [the documentation page](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.html) for it. My suspicion is that either you are using an older Tcl version (8.4 or before!) or you are using a non-standard Tcl distribution (such as the ones written in Java or C#; those have different command profiles, often due to differing amounts of developer effort available). Another possibility is a restricted Tcl interpreter (a "safe" interpreter), but `dict` is put in those by default.

Use `info patchlevel` to find out exactly what version you are *really* using. If it is classic 8.4, there is an *unsupported* dict package out there that does part of what the built-in command does; it was a backport based on early drafts of the Tcl built-in, and hasn't been necessary for mainstream Tcl for many years.

Comment: The system binary version for many tools is often vastly far behind current practice. This is the system vendor's problem; tool makers have no control over them.

Comment: hello thanks for our response  , only  the dict command is valid  on tclsh  but not valid  inside file tcl  like  following test                                                                                   $ tclsh% puts [dict create key1 val1 key2 val2]
key1 val1 key2 val2
% info patchlevel
8.6.10
%